# Ошибка при подключении адаптера для Spinner

Tags: android

При попытке подключить адаптер:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.input_words_spinner_1);
ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.times, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

На последней строке вылетает программа. Вот код массива:

```
<string-array name="times">
    <item>Один</item>
    <item>Два</item>
</string-array>
```

stacktrace ошибки:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.InputData_DialogActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.InputData_DialogActivity.onCreate(InputData_DialogActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Вот код `Spinner`a:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/input_words_spinner_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_words_linearLayout_1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_words_frameLayout_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/input_words_button_1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background_one"
        android:text="@string/button_2"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ну так у вас же не впервые NPE... Ваш Spinner = null.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, но в прошлый раз я перепутал переменную, сначала "заинфлейтировал" все в переменную `v`, а потом в `onClick` из нее пытался достать, хотя там уже была другая переменная. А тут что не так? В `layout` файле этот элемент точно есть, почему ошибка?

Comment: Если он есть, то спиннер не должен быть null. А он null. Парадокс.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я добавил код `layout` со `Spinner`. Он там есть. Может ошибка в другом?

Comment: Ну может вы в активити разметку не ту в setContentView() загрузили... Хз. Выглядит нормально.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я сначала `Spinner` ищу, а потом разметку ставлю.

Comment: Ну так в этом и проблема. До setContentView() разметки нема и в ней найти ничего нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Искать элементы разметки надо только после её загрузки, т.е. после вызова

```
setContentView():
```

Comment: А до ее загрузки никак нельзя?

Comment: Да, никак......